# Web Inspector in Safari 5.1 (Lion) not logging request when not open

Tags: macos, safari

Is there any way to revert Web Inspector in Safari 5.1 to the old behaviour that if I have developer tools enabled, all Ajax/XHR, image, css etc requests are logged and when I open Web Inspector, they are available?

Now it seems that they only get logged when Web Inspector is open - so if I run into an Ajax issue on my dev site and have closed it meanwhile, I cannot any longer just open WI and see the result of the Ajax request, but instead have to reload the page and try to reproduce the problem once more.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or done on purpose for performance reasons. I agree it takes us more time until we "learn" to start early with the inspector.